# excess whitespace in php echo

Tags: php, whitespace

I'm having an issue with my server's PHP echo function.

For some reason, everytime I call "echo", whatever echoes ends up with six or seven extra spaces in front of it, resulting in something like this:

```
echo "hello world"           //ends up like:
             hello world    //instead of:
     hello world
```

any ideas on what's happening?

it's happening across my ENTIRE server (weirdly, yesterday it worked fine. I didn't touch the php settings or anything)

here's just an example of a script that shows this error:

posts URI to database

```
require_once("../../m/includes/globals.php");
$user = DB_Login($_POST["username"], $_POST["password"]);
$uri = mysql_escape_string($_POST["uri"]);
$userID = $user['userID'];
$result = DB_ExecuteQuery("UPDATE driver SET windowsPhoneID = '$uri' WHERE userID = '$userID'" );
if ($result === FALSE) { 
echo "error occurred during updating"; 
} 
echo "success!";
```

Comment: have you used css such as text-align: center; or <center> before or within the container that the echo is within?

Comment: What else is in your PHP files?

Comment: @Andrew, nope, no CSS or anything, I'm basically just trying to get a response of "success" or "failure" from a data POST. so:

if (!something)
{
    echo "failed";
}
echo "success!";

and ThiefMaster, not much, as I explained earlier, it's just some if statements to see if POSTing to a database is successful or not

Comment: Show us the code, as I always tell our support-team: "if I can't reproduce it - I can't fix it" ;)

Comment: exactly same thing happens to me! driving me crazy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have a closing php tag at the end of m/includes/globals.php? Maybe there is some whitespace after the closing tag.

Comment: yup! i have closing tags for every file that is in the "require_once"

Comment: Probably a good idea not to do that; most PHP style guides recommend against it. There is no need for them in included files and it's easy to get rogue whitespace output to the browser causing problems with sessions, cookies, redirects etc.

Comment: Hmmm that I didn't know, I'll give it a look see what happens

Comment: Great! but just wondering what does the whie spaces after the `?>` tag has relation with `echo`?

Comment: i have this thing happening on my server as well. i don't have unented ?> tags anywhere. this happens only if there are some <tag> in the printed string